# Plane wave reflection

Tags: waves, reflection, microwaves

Using the plane wave reflection equation...
$$1-R=T \space ?$$

I cannot find the symbol of reflection constant so i will  call it as "L"

```
       1+L = T
```

What does this 1 mean in this equation?

Answer (score 2):

A boundary is defined as the line or surface between two different types of materials. For any given boundary, that reflects and/or transmits, we can give it transmission $T$ and reflection $R$ constants to find the amount of reflected or transmitted stuff(like light). 
$$\text{Stuff} \cdot R = \text{Reflected Stuff}$$
$$\text{Stuff} \cdot T = \text{Transmitted Stuff}$$
We know that "Stuff" does not usually magically disappear so we can add the reflected and transmitted stuff together and find it is equal to the initial "Stuff".
$$\text{Stuff} = \text{Reflected Stuff} + \text{Transmitted Stuff}$$
We can now algebraically simplify this to ...
$$\text{Stuff} = \text{Stuff} \cdot R + \text{Stuff} \cdot T $$
Divide all terms by "Stuff"
$$1 = R + T $$
And finally
$$1 - R = T $$
So the one represents all the "Stuff" to be colliding with the boundary.